# Why do we need elimination theory for solving systems of polynomial equation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am currently working through the book "Ideals,Varieties and Algorithms". There I learned how to efficiently solve a system of polynomial equations when I use Gröbner-Bases which kind of eliminate the variables in the best possible way, so that it is not a big problem anymore to find the solutions.

Now I am a bit confused about the purpose of elimination theory and elimination orderings(comes directly after the Chapter of Gröbner-Bases). Why should I know this ?

Comment: "Not a big problem anymore to find the solutions"? Buchberger’s Gröbner bases algorithm is double exponential in the number of variables.

Comment: So in practice one doesn't really use Buchberger’s Gröbner bases algorithm, when the polynomial system is too "big" ?

Comment: A Gröbner basis is always with respect to a monomial ordering. What ordering were you using previously when solving a system of polynomial equations? I'm guessing it was probably an elimination ordering. The whole point of an elimination ordering is to get a Gröbner basis whose last element involves as few variables as possible. Then we can find the zeroes of that polynomial and back substitute to extend these to solutions of the whole system.

Comment: Now I am a bit confused. In our lecture we used lex, deglex and degrevlex monomial ordering but we rarely have spoken about elimination ordering when computing Gröbner-Bases with the Buchberger algorithm. From what I have read so far, it seems that every elimination ordering is a monomial ordering but not the other way round, isn't it ?. Lex should be one.